# Get coordinate with NaN at x axis

Tags: rxjs

i got the following block of code to generate a new enemy each 1.5.

each new enemy is added to an array using scan operator

i did the replace suggested.

i did a small change to be able to replicate

```js
const enemies$ = rxjs.from([0,1])
    .pipe(
        rxjs.scan( (enemyArray) => {
            const enemy = {
                x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                y: -30
            }
            console.log(enemy)
            enemyArray.push(enemy);
            console.log(enemyArray); //debug.
            return enemyArray;
        }, [])
    );

    enemies$.subscribe(
      (enemies) => console.log(enemies) 
    );
```

The result in the console is the following for the first element (enemy)

```bash
{x: 312, y: -30}
```

But when the enemy is added to enemyArray , the following results are shown in the console

```bash
(1)[{...}]
0: {x: NaN, y: 515}
1: {x: NaN, y: 65}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to parse a number from a string which was a number? `Math.round(Math.random() * canvas.width)`

Comment: What value does `canvas.width` have?

Comment: canvas is global variable.  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

Comment: My question was, what value does `canvas.width` have? Not what is `canvas`

Comment: canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

Comment: Yes but what value is it???? Can you debug and tell us exactly what value it has in the expression `parseInt(String(Math.random() * canvas.width), 10)`

Comment: I did a small change to remove canvas.width, for a fixed number

Answer (score 0):

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) takes a string as the first argument, so it should be

```
parseInt(String(Math.random() * 100), 10)
```

Comment: Thanks i did the replace and still happen the same

Comment: Shouldn't be happening @RafaelAvaria check out this StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kkdhby?file=index.ts